# Вопрос по реализации контроллеров в ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Возник такой вопрос. У меня допустим сайтом будут пользоваться 3 вида пользователей, один из них администратор. Есть у меня например контроллер администратора: AdministratorController. Администратор например много вещей может делать, например CRUD абонементов. Так вот: правильно обращаться к репозиторию абонементов в контроллере администратора, и потом создавать в этом же контроллере метод что-то типа **CreateAbonement** и там уже внутри работать. Или же создавать отдельно контроллер абонементов, в нем создавать метод по созданию, но только указать параметр Authorize с указанием роли администратора? То есть мы под каждую сущность создаем свой контроллер, или контроллеры создаем под сущности "пользователей"?

Comment: У вас есть сотрудники "Маша", "Петя", "Егор", "Ира", и так далее - будете каждому сотруднику делать свой контроллер? Ну согласитесь, как-то странно звучит, да? Как быть? А все зависит от ваших потребностей. Например, вы можете сделать отдельную страницу для редактирования записей, где админы будут иметь весь доступ, бухгалтер допустим будет иметь возможность только просмотра. Или вы можете сделать информацию о пользователе (который видит обычный человек), но если на эту страницу зайдет администратор, то он может прям напрямую редактировать данные пользователя. Вариантов уйма, выбирайте с умом)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы делаете REST API, то контроллеры обязательно создаются под сущности. Нужно сделать AbonementController и в нем реализовать метод POST для создания экземпляра. Этот метод должен быть разрешен только администратору.

Если вы делаете просто RPC, то, теоретически, можно сделать контроллер администратора и в нем реализовать метод CreateAbonement, но это может привести к тому, что контроллер администратора разрастется и будет тяжел в поддержке, поэтому в такой модели тоже более удобно делать контроллеры по сущностям, либо по группам активностей с сущностью, например в вашем случае для RPC я бы сделал контроллер AbonementManagementController.

[Тут](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/compare/the-difference-between-rpc-and-rest/) полезная статья от Amazon.